# Passing multiple parameters to pool.map() function in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, map-function

I need some way to use a function within pool.map() that accepts more than one parameter. As per my understanding, the target function of pool.map() can only have one iterable as a parameter but is there a way that I can pass other parameters in as well? In this case, I need to pass in a few configuration variables, like my Lock() and logging information to the target function.

I have tried to do some research and I think that I may be able to use partial functions to get it to work? However I don't fully understand how these work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is a simple example of what I want to do:

```
def target(items, lock):
    for item in items:
        # Do cool stuff
        if (... some condition here ...):
            lock.acquire()
            # Write to stdout or logfile, etc.
            lock.release()

def main():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(target(PASS PARAMS HERE), iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments (I have used J.F. Sebastien's "star" method successfully)

Comment: Please, whenever you use multiprocessing use a try/finally clause, with close() and join() inside finally to ensure processes are closed if an error happens.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506489/python-multiprocessing-leading-to-many-zombie-processes

Comment: @zeehio Shouldn't that be automatic?

Comment: @endolith It should, but usually it is not. If the main python program ends all its children are killed/reaped, but if the main program keeps running (e.g. because the parallelization component is a minor part of the whole program), you will need something (e.g. try/finally) to ensure all processes are terminated.

Comment: don't use close(), use the pool in a context:

with multiProc.Pool(3) as my_pool:

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this (as you suspected):

```
from functools import partial

def target(lock, iterable_item):
    for item in iterable_item:
        # Do cool stuff
        if (... some condition here ...):
            lock.acquire()
            # Write to stdout or logfile, etc.
            lock.release()

def main():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    l = multiprocessing.Lock()
    func = partial(target, l)
    pool.map(func, iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Example:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    print("{} {} {}".format(a, b, c))

def main():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    a = "hi"
    b = "there"
    func = partial(f, a, b)
    pool.map(func, iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
hi there 1
hi there 2
hi there 3
hi there 4
hi there 5
```

Comment: those who have a problem with the lock, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557686/python-sharing-a-lock-between-processes/25558333#25558333

Comment: What if the variable is in first position?  Such as `test(input, p1, p2, p3=None)` , I have `p1, p2, p3` fixed, and `input` vary ?

Comment: @Mithril Write a top-level function like this: `def mytest(p1, p2, input, p3=None): test(input, p1, p2, p3=None)` Then do `func = partial(mytest, some_p1, some_p2, p3=some_p3)`, and pass `func` to `pool.map`.

Answer (score 12):

You could use a map function that allows multiple arguments, as does the fork of `multiprocessing` found in `pathos`.

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> 
>>> def add_and_subtract(x,y):
...   return x+y, x-y
... 
>>> res = Pool().map(add_and_subtract, range(0,20,2), range(-5,5,1))
>>> res
[(-5, 5), (-2, 6), (1, 7), (4, 8), (7, 9), (10, 10), (13, 11), (16, 12), (19, 13), (22, 14)]
>>> Pool().map(add_and_subtract, *zip(*res))
[(0, -10), (4, -8), (8, -6), (12, -4), (16, -2), (20, 0), (24, 2), (28, 4), (32, 6), (36, 8)]
```

`pathos` enables you to easily nest hierarchical parallel maps with multiple inputs, so we can extend our example to demonstrate that.

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ThreadingPool as TPool
>>> 
>>> res = TPool().amap(add_and_subtract, *zip(*Pool().map(add_and_subtract, range(0,20,2), range(-5,5,1))))
>>> res.get()
[(0, -10), (4, -8), (8, -6), (12, -4), (16, -2), (20, 0), (24, 2), (28, 4), (32, 6), (36, 8)]
```

Even more fun, is to build a nested function that we can pass into the Pool.
This is possible because `pathos` uses `dill`, which can serialize almost anything in python.

```
>>> def build_fun_things(f, g):
...   def do_fun_things(x, y):
...     return f(x,y), g(x,y)
...   return do_fun_things
... 
>>> def add(x,y):
...   return x+y
... 
>>> def sub(x,y):
...   return x-y
... 
>>> neato = build_fun_things(add, sub)
>>> 
>>> res = TPool().imap(neato, *zip(*Pool().map(neato, range(0,20,2), range(-5,5,1))))
>>> list(res)
[(0, -10), (4, -8), (8, -6), (12, -4), (16, -2), (20, 0), (24, 2), (28, 4), (32, 6), (36, 8)]
```

If you are not able to go outside of the standard library, however, you will have to do this another way.  Your best bet in that case is to use `multiprocessing.starmap` as seen here: [Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments) (noted by @Roberto in the comments on the OP's post)

Get `pathos` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't have access to `functools.partial`, you could use a wrapper function for this, as well.

```
def target(lock):
    def wrapped_func(items):
        for item in items:
            # Do cool stuff
            if (... some condition here ...):
                lock.acquire()
                # Write to stdout or logfile, etc.
                lock.release()
    return wrapped_func

def main():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    lck = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool.map(target(lck), iterable)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This makes `target()` into a function that accepts a lock (or whatever parameters you want to give), and it will return a function that only takes in an iterable as input, but can still use all your other parameters. That's what is ultimately passed in to `pool.map()`, which then should execute with no problems.

Comment: I'm super late on this, but this code won't work, because nested functions can't be pickled. Calling `target(lck)` returns the nested `wrapped_func` function, which needs to be pickled to be passed to the worker process, and that will always fail.