# multiprocessing pool.map on a function inside other function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Say I have a function that provides different results for the same input and needs to be performed multiple times for the same input to obtain mean (I'll sketch a trivial example, but in reality the source of randomness is `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection` if that matters)

```
define f(a,b):
    output=[]
    for i in range(0,b):
        output[i] = np.mean(np.random.rand(a,))
    return np.mean(output)
```

The arguments for this function are defined inside another function like so (again, a trivial example, please don't mind if these are not efficient/pythonistic):

```
define g(c,d):
    a = c
    b = c*d
    result=f(a,b)
    return(result)
```

Instead of using a `for` loop, I want to use `multiprocessing` to speed up the execution time. I found that neither `pool.apply` nor `pool.startmap` do the trick (execution time goes up), only `pool.map` works. However, it can only take one argument (in this case - the number of iterations). I tried redefining `f` as follows:

```
define f(number_of_iterations):
    output=np.mean(np.random.rand(a,))
    return output
```

And then use `pool.map` as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
define g(c,d):
    temp=[]
    a = c
    b = c*d
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    temp = pool.map(f, [number_of_iterations for number_of_iterations in b])
    pool.close()
    result=np.mean(temp)
    return(result)
```

Basically, a convoluted workaround to make `f` a one-argument function. The hope was that `f` would still pick up argument `a`, however, executing `g` results in an error about `a` not being defined.

Is there any way to make pool.map work in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `functool.partial` solves your issue. Here is a implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25553970/9177173 Here the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial