# how to parallelize a loop in python with a function with several arguments?

Tags: python, loops, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize a for loop in python that must execute a function with several arguments, one of which will be changing through the loop. The loop itself needs to be embedded in a function.
I have already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553919/passing-multiple-parameters-to-pool-map-function-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop/9786225#9786225) in stackoverflow and beyond ([here](https://further-reading.net/2017/01/quick-tutorial-python-multiprocessing/) and [here](https://dev.to/terrillo/a-quick-introduction-to-python-multiprocessing-pools-speeding-up-your-workflow-17op)) but I just cannot make it work :(

Below is a MWE:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def mytestFun(otherStuff, myparams):
    return myparams[0]*otherStuff - myparams[1]

def myfun1(extraParams, mylist):
    [myMat, otherStuff] = extraParams
    
    for ivals in mylist:
        myparams = myMat[ivals,:]
        result = mytestFun(otherStuff, myparams)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    myMat = np.random.uniform(0,1,(6,2))
    extraParams = [myMat, 5]
    print(myfun1(extraParams, a_list))
    pool = Pool()
    func = partial(myfun1, extraParams)
    pool.map(func, a_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

And I keep getting errors that I don't know how to interpret:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exampleMultiProcessing.py", line 61, in <module>
    pool.map(func, a_list)
  File "/Users/laurama/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/Users/laurama/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here dask.delayed can be your friend

Comment: @ laura We can use joblib here;

Answer (score 3):

You can read about joblib [here](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html). Basically when we use joblib, it expects that we will be passing it the args for the function which we want to parallelise. So here i am passing the args directly to the function, that's why i am looping using the [underscore_variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python), you can use anything there, no issues at all. Basically I am ignoring the looping variable using the `_`;

And yes, Parallel automatically will distribute it over n_cores;

Try this:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed    

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    a_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
    myMat = np.random.uniform(0,1,(6,2)) 
    extraParams = [myMat, 5] 
    print(myfun1(extraParams, a_list)) 
    result = Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(myfun1)(extraParams, a_list) for _ in range(1))[0]
```

Comment: it does thank you, but could you please provide more context? I don't understand very much what the solution is doing, in particular, this part:
for _ in range(1)) in fact, I have never seen an underscore for a variable.
Also, would Parallel automatically distribute the loop among the n_jobs? 
Thanks!

Comment: @Laura; Apologies, i have updated the answer now; Let me know!

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what happens, but a quick check finds that this solution is actually significantly slower than just doing the loop both with this trivial example and with my real example... Any ideas?

Comment: Ahh now I see why it's slower; you are having a loop over input's, I didn't see that. In that case we need to change the looping strategy in; try modifying it to loop over that array of yours(IE. On your inputs)